# Disable .htaccess redirect if localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this `.htacess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects any sub domain of domain.co.uk to the root domain.co.uk e.g. test.domain.co.uk goes to domain.co.uk

However I have noticed if I try to access this site locally it redirects localhost/domain/ to domain.co.uk, can I add some lines to not do the redirect if on http://localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add `localhost` in negative condition to stop redirecting `localhost` like this:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|domain\.co\.uk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: That appears to work, thank you - however could you explain exactly how that works in regards to differentiating between localhost and domain.co.uk, im unsure what !^(localhost|domain\.co\.uk) means? It sorta reads like if not localhost or domain.co.uk

Comment: `if not localhost or domain.co.uk` yes you read it almost correct, it means if `HTTP_HOST` is not `localhost` AND `HTTP_HOST` is not `domain.co.uk`. There is a negative operator `!` at the start and `|` in regex is for `OR` or alternation.